# How to inspect app storage on Android?

Tags: android, storage

So I've just discovered that the debug version of my app takes up a whopping 155MB of data by startup. Obviously this is unacceptable, and I'm trying to determine what's causing the bloat. What options do I have for investigating this issue?

Comment: and what's your apk size?

Comment: @BartekLipinski 15.5 MB, which should be smaller but isn't the cause of this problem.

Comment: So your app gets installed and all of a sudden it uses 155MB? Is it the number the Application Manager gives you?

Comment: After some experimenting it looks like logging into Spotify using their SDK is causing 30 MBs to be used up suddenly. Still working to figure out if it's all coming from Spotify since that still leaves a bit to be accounted for, but it looks like that might be the culprit. Still no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

i think your app memory leak, you could use Androids Memory Monitor.
this blog can help you.[blog]:https://riggaroo.co.za/fixing-memory-leaks-in-android-outofmemoryerror/

Comment: Would a memory leak cause the storage size to balloon? I would think that would be a ram issue. Or are they reported together?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by LeakCanary. When the leak data can't be recorded, it will cache it under the app's directory until storage permission to the leak app is granted. This created the illusion of size. In production this will not be an issue.